# Unsupported parameters for (cisco.asa.asa_command) module: context, passwords found in provider

Tags: ansible, cisco, asa

I am trying to send a 'show version' command to my Cisco ASA using Ansible, but I am encountering the following errors and I don't know why. The same thing works for my Cisco router though. Below are some details that might be helpful.

```
Cisco Asa version -> 9.12(2)9

Ansible version -> 2.9.13 

Python version -> 2.7.17
```

Ansible hosts:

```
#This is a group of remote servers with GUI
[gui]
ubuntu ansible_user=admin

#These are global variables for the group Cisco
[cisco:vars]
ansible_connection=local
ansible_network_os=ios

#This is a group of remote servers for Cisco devices
[cisco]
cisco_router ansible_user=admin

[firewall:vars]
ansible_connection=local

[firewall]
cisco_asa ansible_user=admin
```

Asa playbook:

```
- name: "Connecting to Cisco ASA"
hosts: firewall
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: run show version on remote devices
      cisco.asa.asa_command:
        commands:
          - show version
```

Error encoutering:

```
fatal: [cisco_asa]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (cisco.asa.asa_command) module: context, passwords found in provider. Supported parameters include: auth_pass, authorize, host, password, port, ssh_keyfile, timeout, username"}
```

Full error with -vvv:

```
fatal: [cisco_asa]: FAILED! => {
"ansible_facts": {
"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
},
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"authorize": null,
"commands": [
"show version"
],
"context": null,
"interval": 1,
"match": "all",
"passwords": null,
"provider": {
"auth_pass": null,
"authorize": false,
"context": null,
"host": null,
"password": null,
"passwords": null,
"port": null,
"ssh_keyfile": null,
"timeout": null,
"username": null
},
"retries": 10,
"wait_for": null
}
},
"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (cisco.asa.asa_command) module: context, passwords found in provider. Supported parameters include: auth_pass, authorize, host, password, port, ssh_keyfile, timeout, username"
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to ansible 2.10.x, make sure you installed the cisco.asa latest collection and try again.

Comment: What does using [`asa_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/asa_command_module.html#) as task rather than `cisco.asa.asa_command`? The module [`cisco.asa.asa_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/asa/asa_command_module.html) is the name only as of Ansible 2.10, which is introducing the collection concept.

Comment: Did you actually try any of the above recommendations ? What was the result ?

Comment: None of them worked for me. I upgraded to 2.10.X, the issue was still there. I used cisco.asa.asa_command  but still couldn't connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the below variables in my host file and installing paramiko with pip command fixed the issue for me:

```
ansible_user=admin
ansible_ssh_pass=*****
ansible_become_method=enable
ansible_become_pass=*****
ansible_connection=ansible.netcommon.network_cli
ansible_network_os=cisco.asa.asa
ansible_python_interpreter=python
```

Answer (score 0):

The following error indicates that during the execution of ios_command module an unsupported parameter 'command' was found. Do check the Ansible document [1] for the support parameters in the ios_command module.

```
--------------------------------------
"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ios_command) module: command Supported parameters include: auth_pass, authorize, commands, host, interval, match, password, port, provider, retries, ssh_keyfile, timeout, username, wait_for"
--------------------------------------
```

After looking at your playbook 'command' is not supported in ios_command module 'commands' is the correct parameter.
. Its better to refer the standard ansible documentations.